# Using jQuery's Datepicker to show only 3 weekdays

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, getdate

i'm quite new to javascript and code overall.
I'm using a datepicker at my wordpress block and i created this little code (after searching stackoverflows forums) and it serves me well to what i needed so far:

```
$("#input_4_14").datepicker({
    minDate: 1,
    beforeShowDay: function (d) {
        return (1 == d.getDay() ? [true, ''] : [false, '']);
    }
});
```

`input_x_y` refers to the datepicker i'm using at the form(x) and the `datepicker(y)`.

What it does (and does correctly) is limit the past days and shows only monday.

What i don't know how to do is to show only monday, friday and saturday.
I tried doing:

`1,5,6==d.getday()`
but it doesn't work.

Could anyone give me a hand here?

UPDATE:
I redid the code like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
var days = [1, 5, 6];
jQuery.noConflict(); 
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$("#input_4_14").datepicker({
    minDate: 1,
    beforeShowDay: function (d) {
        return [$.inArray(d.getDay(), days) > -1, ''];
    }
});
  });
</script>
```

but it still doesn't work.
Side note: i'm using Wordpress with HTML Javascript widget.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the days you want to allow in an array an then use [$.inArray()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray) to test whether the current day is a valid one

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var days = [1, 5, 6];
    $("#input_4_14").datepicker({
        minDate: 1,
        beforeShowDay: function (d) {
            return [$.inArray(d.getDay(), days) > -1, ''];
        }
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/xeLdV/)

Comment: So, here's the final code i'm using, for some reason it's not working:
<script type='text/javascript'>
var days = [1, 5, 6];
jQuery.noConflict();
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$("#input_4_14").datepicker({
    minDate: 1,
    beforeShowDay: function (d) {
        return [$.inArray(d.getDay(), days) > -1, ''];
    }
});
  });
</script>

Did i do something wrong?

Comment: @user3075146 no I don't think so... any error in your browser console? see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/xeLdV/4/

Comment: You are right, i forgot to change the ID for the DATEPICKER inside the form. I've corrected it and it's working like a charm.